# TypeError while updating Custom element created with LitElement

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component, lit-element

I created an element with URL and value properties. The value property takes in a JSON and populates the mwc-textfield. the element makes an AJAX GET call when the URL link is inputted and the JSON obtained is passed into the element as the value, thereby populating the mwc-textfields. This works well when the appropriate URL is passed. But I get a type error if a wrong URL is passed or an empty string is passed into the URL property(`<my-el url=""></my-el>`). A figure of the error is attached below
How can I reformat the element to show the default element when an empty string is passed to the URL property and update only when the ajax response obtained is the same with the value format

```
 <my-el value= '[
    {
      "coding": [
        {
          "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
          "code": "166643006",
          "display": "Liver enzymes abnormal"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]'></my-el>

 <my-el url="http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Medication/30072"></my-el>

import {LitElement, html} from 'lit-element'
import '@material/mwc-textfield/mwc-textfield.js'
import '@material/mwc-formfield/mwc-formfield.js'
import '@polymer/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.js'


class myEl extends LitElement {

    static get properties(){
        return{
            url: {type: String},
            value: {type: Array}
        };
    };

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.value = [{coding:[{}]}];
    };


    render(){
        if(typeof(this.value)=="string"){
            this.value = JSON.parse(this.value);
          }
        
        return html `
        <div id ="reasonDiv">
        ${this.value[0].coding.map((i,index) => html `
        <mwc-textfield id="codeFieldID" outlined label ="code" .value = "${i.code || ""}" 
        @input = "${e=>this.value[0].coding[index].code = e.target.value}"></mwc-textfield>

        <mwc-textfield id="systemFieldID" outlined label ="system" .value= "${i.system || ""}" 
        @input = "${e =>this.value[0].coding[index].system =e.target.value}"></mwc-textfield>

        <mwc-textfield id="displayFieldID" outlined .value ="${i.display || ""}"
        @input = "${e => this.value[0].coding[index].display =e.target.value}"></mwc-textfield>
        `)}
        </mwc-formfield>
        </div>
        <iron-ajax id ="ajax" auto bubbles handle-as ="json" .url ="${this.url}"></iron-ajax>      
      `    
    }

    
  /**updated() delivers only after render*/
  updated(){
    this.shadowRoot.getElementById('ajax').addEventListener('iron-ajax-response', function (e){
        let statusReason = this.parentNode.host;
        if (e.detail.response.code !== undefined){
            statusReason.value = e.detail.response.statusReason

        }else {
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.getElementById("reasonDiv"));
        }
    })
}
};

customElements.define('my-el',myEl);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a try-catch? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is happening when you call `this.value[0]`, but `this.value` is `undefined` so you can't call an indexer on it.

You also have a circular reference where setting `this.value` causes `render` to fire, but then in `render` you set `this.value` again. As a general rule try to avoid *side effects*: in `render` don't set properties that affect subsequent calls to `render`.

Next up, you have `</mwc-formfield>` but no opening tag, that will probably be handled but you should fix it.

I think the root cause of your problem is whatever sets the `value` attribute, but better error checking could help you identify that:

```
render(){
    if(!this.value)
        return html`No value set`;

    const parsed = typeof this.value === 'string' ? JSON.parse(this.value) : this.value;
    if(!(parsed?.length > 0))
        return html`Value array is unpopulated: ${this.value}`;

    return html`
<div id ="reasonDiv">
    ${parsed[0].coding.map((i,index) => html ` ... `)}
</div>
<iron-ajax id="ajax" auto bubbles handle-as="json" 
    .url=${this.url}></iron-ajax>`;
}
```

Then inside your loop you're creating the set events: `@input= ${e=>this.value[0].coding[index].code = e.target.value}` - this will likely cause issues because `this.value` might be a string, and setting the child won't cause a re-render, but other changes might.

There are a couple of ways around this - I usually use a readonly copy of the server data and update a completely different object to send back user input, but if you want this to be mutable you should implement error handling here too.

Replace the inline calls with a dedicated function, something like:

```
return html`
...
${parsed[0].coding.map((i,index) => html ` ... 
    <mwc-textfield id="codeFieldID" outlined label ="code" .value = "${i.code || ""}" 
        @input=${e=>this.setValue('code', i, index, e.target.value)}></mwc-textfield>
    ...`)}
...`;

setValue(key, coding, index, value) {

    if(!this.value)
        this.value = [{coding:[{[key]: value}]}];
    else {
        const parsed = typeof this.value === 'string' ? JSON.parse(this.value) : this.value;
        parsed[0].coding[index][key] = value;
    }
}
```

This makes it far easier to add breakpoints, `console.log` or whatever debugging to track this down.

Finally, you can skip the JSON parse entirely within Lit with `.property` syntax:

```
html`
 <my-el .value=${[
    {
      coding: [
        {
          system: "http://snomed.info/sct",
          code: "166643006",
          display: "Liver enzymes abnormal"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]}></my-el>
`;
```